# Why does this unhash function not reverse this hash?

Tags: actionscript-3, hash, actionscript, cryptography, bit-manipulation

I wrote a hashing function for password and key generation, but realized pretty quickly that being able to reverse the hash was quite valuable, so i wrote an opposite function, however, it dosent work. I dont get why this DOESNT work.

```
function hash64(n:uint):uint
{
    n = (~n) + (n << 21);
    n = n ^ (n >> 24);
    n = (n + (n << 3)) + (n << 8);
    n = n ^(n >> 14);
    n = (n + (n << 2)) + (n << 4);
    n = n ^ (n >> 28);
    n = n + (n << 31);
    return n;
}

function unhash64(n:uint):uint
{
    n = (~n) - (n >> 21);
    n = n ^ (n << 24);
    n = (n - (n >> 3)) - (n >> 8);
    n = n ^ (n << 14);
    n = (n - (n >> 2)) - (n >> 4);
    n = n ^ (n << 28);
    n = n - (n >> 31);
    return n;
}
```

Output when fed 1000:

```
Hashed from 1000:           1221775646
Unhash output:              1963490760
```

Comment: What did you expect? 1000?

Comment: Yeah, is that impossible?

Comment: That's the point of cryptography, actually: it **should not** be possible to recreate the original data from the hash. Otherwise than bruteforce it over the course of years, that it.

Comment: Organis is right: for password & key generation you would use a secure hash. Secure hashes should be irreversible. What you've generated is not a secure hash (answer converted to a comment, harold does a better job of explaining the primary question).

Answer (score 5):

The first obvious problem is that it's not mirrored in time. That *sometimes* works (if the order of operations didn't matter in the first place), but in general the inverse of `y = f(g(x))` is `x = g⁻¹(f⁻¹(y))`. f was applied last, so it has to be undone first. Compare: if you first put on your socks and then your shoes, you should probably take off your shoes first and then your socks.

Furthermore, many inverses there are just wrong to begin with. For example, the inverse of
`m = n ^ (n >> 24)` is `n = m ^ (m >> 24)`, and the inverse of `m = (n + (n << 2)) + (n << 4)` is `n = m * 0x3cf3cf3d` (it's a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)). It's not as simple as the direction of the shift flipping.

Not tested, but these are all the inverses in the right order:

```
n = n * 0x80000001;
n = n ^ (n >> 28);
n = n * 0x3cf3cf3d;
n = n ^ (n >> 14) ^ (n >> 28);
n = n * 0x1c03dd39;
n = n ^ (n >> 24);
n = (n + 1) * 0xffdfffff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are not reversible.  If you want a reversible function that hides the original input then use an encryption instead.  Encryptions are designed to be reversible, as long as you have the correct key.

There are already well known techniques for password and key generation.  If you attempt to design your own versions then they will be insecure.  That does not matter is all you want to do is to hide things from your kid brother.  If you are working in the commercial area then you might be sued, so use all the standard existing secure methods.  You might want to research Key Derivation Functions like PBKDF2 or argon2.